# How to grab HTML snippet via Applescript with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, applescript

Here is my situation in detail.

I have figured out how to login to a website, not using javascript, but using "keystrokes", "tabs" and "returns" to find the username and password fields.  I know this can be unreliable as websites change but for now I am just trying to keep it simple.

After I log in to a site, like a bank account, I want to grab the account balance and import it to Numbers.

I have figured out how to insert a predermined text into a specific cell in Numbers and probably could expand that to dialog boxes ect, but that is not what I am really trying to accomplish.

Basically I don't know what I need to do to grab the data from the current website after I have logged in.  Doing research I realize it is something todo with javascript.

For now and to apply it to the bigger plan, I just want to know how to locate data of a website that I do not have to log into in Safari via javascript and display the data in the results of Applescript Editor. And I am trying to figure out how I could use that result to display it in another application (ei Numbers).  I then would apply this to other sites, so I would like to know exactly where to look to find the data.

I am thinking that stock websites would be a great example but I am having a tough time finding one that fits this example.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know how to locate data of a website that I do not have
>   to log into in Safari via javascript

This can be easely done with JavaScript: with it you may get dom element(s) by [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName), [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), traverse them [upwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) or [inwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) and get their properties like [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) and [html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) content. Please tells us what have you tried and which error do you get: nobody can learn JavaScript for you.

---

> and display the data in the results of Applescript Editor.

All you have to do to pass a variable from JavaScript to AppleScript is to include a return statement in your js code.

```
property myVar : missing value
tell application "Safari"
    set myVar to do JavaScript "
var myVar = " & myVar & ";
myVar = myVar + 1;
return myVar;
" in document 1
end tell
display dialog myVar
```

The `do JavaScript` command, which is specific to Safari, will return the same value returned by the script it executes. Hence, you may save any value from a webpage to your applescript.