# Get data from webpage using applescript

Tags: html, ios, macos, applescript

I am working on my first applescript. I open a webpage through Safari which is eg: Evernote page - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108 and I wish to get the version and it's latest updated date which lies on the left hand side of the page i.e. under image logo of the app under "Category" it's "Updated" and "Version".

Here is the script I am working on:

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108?"
    activate
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        -- Add the logic to get the updated date and version.
    end tell
end tell
```

Is it possible to get the data from the webpage through applescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that works with Applescript. Probably not the best by far, but a start.

```
set source_code to do shell script "curl https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108"
set int_1 to offset of "class=\"label\">Updated: </span>" in source_code
set int_2 to offset of "<span class=\"label\">Version: </span>" in source_code
set Update_date to characters (int_1 + 30) thru (int_1 + 41) in source_code as string
set Version_text to characters (int_2 + 36) thru (int_2 + 40) in source_code as string

get Update_date & " - " & Version_text
```

A more direct and diverse approach could be:

```
set hyperlink to "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108"

do shell script "curl " & quoted form of hyperlink & " | grep -o 'class=\"label\">Updated: </span>[A-Za-z0-9, ]\\{0,\\}</li><li><span class=\"label\">Version: </span>[0-9 .]\\{0,\\}' | sed 's/class=\"label\">Updated: <\\/span>//g' | sed 's/<\\/li><li><span class=\"label\">Version: <\\/span>/ - /g'"
```

You can replace the Var `hyperlink` to pretty much any app on the iTunes store and it should work the same.

Comment: No bad, since using `curl` is much faster than launching Safari, but I'd use a regular expression to retrieve the strings instead of a fixed number. Something like...  `set Version_text to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of source_code & " | perl -ne 'print \"$1\" if />Version: <\\/span>(.*?)</'"`

Comment: @Vic This is true! Or even better, pipe the `curl` straight to the `perl` :) Except if you want one command line to get both, I would personally curl, then grep -o and then sed or perl to clean out the Html and just have the update date and version. Something like: `curl https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote/id281796108 | grep -o 'class=\"label\">Updated: </span>[A-Za-z0-9, ]\{0,\}</li><li><span class="label">Version: </span>[0-9 .]\{0,\}' | sed 's/class="label">Updated: <\/span>//g' | sed 's/<\/li><li><span class="label">Version: <\/span>/ - /g'`

Answer (score 0):

The way you manipulate Web pages with AppleScript is you use the AppleScript command “do javascript” to run a JavaScript on the Web page. JavaScript is designed for manipulating Web pages, so it has all the right tools to get the values of a text node or whatever you want to do.

[How to grab HTML snippet via Applescript with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487595/how-to-grab-html-snippet-via-applescript-with-javascript/)